# fftw simd-altivec.h cannot compile

Tags: simd, xcode4.4, fftw, altivec

I'm using fftw on a Mac using Xcode 4.4. In my project, I added the whole fftw source code into the project and tried to compile it.

It cannot compile successfully, because in the simd-altivec.h, it gives errors like these:

---

ALTIVEC only works in single precision

compiling simd-altivec.h requires -maltivec or equivalent

unknown type vector

unknown type V

---

My questions are:

What is a better way to add a third party library into my project? Directly adding all the source file into my project seems awkward to me...

Second, how should I deal with the errors in simd-altivec.h? what does simd-altivec.h do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just build FFTW the normal way and then add the compiled library (e.g. `libfftw3.a`) and header (`fftw3.h`) to your Xcode project.

E.g. to build and install FFTW from the command line for single precision (float) (`libfftw3f.a`):

```
$ ./configure --enable-float --enable-sse
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

For double precision (`libfftw3.a`):

```
$ ./configure --enable-sse2
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Alternatively you can just use the excellent [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) package manager which takes care of everything for you:

```
$ sudo brew install fftw
```

---

Note: `simd-altivec.h` is for PowerPC builds with AltiVec SIMD.